# Scala - Dynamic Code generation using scala reflection

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, eval, apache-spark-sql

I have a requirement where I need to add multiple columns to a spark dataframe.

I am using `dataframe.withColumn` for adding the new column. I want the code to be dynamically generated at run time as the new columns to be added are defined by the user at run time.

I'm using `Eval.scala` in the below link for dynamic execution

Eval.scala
https://gist.github.com/xuwei-k/9ba39fe22f120cb098f4

The code below works:

```
val df: DataFrame = sqlContext.read.load("somefile.parquet")    
  val schema = StructType(
    StructField("k", StringType, true) ::
      StructField("v", IntegerType, false) :: Nil)
 //Create Empty DataFrame
  var df2: DataFrame = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD[Row], schema)     
//Add new column
Eval[Unit](s"${df2 = df.withColumn("""Segment""", lit("""SOFT DRINKS"""))}")
//Displays the dataframe content
df2.show
```

When I try to build the code above as string and pass it to Eval, it fails

```
var strDF: String= "df2 = df.withColumn(" + """"Segment"""" + ", lit(" + """"SOFT DRINKS"""" + "))"
Eval[Unit](s"${strDF}")
```

The above code fails as `"not found: value df2"`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I guess the problem originated from parsing string into input for Eval.  Check parsing implementation for Eval

Comment: Shouldn't it be `val df2 = df.withColumn(...`?

Comment: @LiMuBei, I've already declared df2 and populated with empty dataframe.